# Error happened: TypeError: expected dynamic type string', but had typeint64 react native

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native

I use react native with Android,When I use `ListView` or `ScrollView`,this problem happened,

My **package.json** is

```
{
  "name": "ImagesPickerSearch",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-native start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react-native": "^0.17.0",
    "react-native-fileupload": "git+https://github.com/PhilippKrone/react-native-fileupload.git",
    "react-native-image-picker": "^0.12.4"
  }
}
```

Android **build.gradle** is:

```
dependencies {
        compile fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
        compile "co 
     m.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1"
        compile "com.facebook.react:react-native:0.18.+"
```

but in IOS,that works well,who can help me